# How to find particular text from label in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a label like this:

```
  <label class="lblclass">Claim 12J-12 closed</label>
```

Now i have a function like this:

```
function getdata(numberdata){
    $(".lblClass").find(numberdata)
}
```

By clicking on some link i pass the data as `<a href="#" onclick="getdata(12J-12)"></a>`

Now my question:
 i need to find "`numberdata`" from label and apply hyperlink to that number. But i'm not able to find the `numberdata` from `label`. Can any one please help me to find the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find and replace the desired number from the label using `replace` function and `wrap` the text with `anchor` tag as under.

Try this,

```
function getdata(numberdata)
{
    $(".lblClass").replace(numberdata, "<a href='#'>" + numberdata + "</a>");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/otodaw/1/edit)*

HTML:

```
  <a class="getdata" href="#" data-get="12J-12">getdata</a>  
  <label class="lblclass">Claim 12J-12 closed</label>
```

using the `data` attribute and this bit of jquery

jQuery ( use `:contains` selector! ):

```
$('.getdata').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var myData= $(this).data('get');
  
  $('.lblclass:contains('+ myData +')').wrap('<a href="'+myData+'" />'); 
});
```

`wrap()` will create a link around your label.
Adjust the href as you like to get the right URL.